# Write dictionary in order of keys into Plist

Tags: swift, plist, property-list

I have a dictionary  (with Dictionary being ) which I'm trying to write in order of the keys into a plist. Writing without order is not too complicated:

```
do  {
    let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: dic, format: PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.openStep, options: 0)
    do {
        try data.write(to: customPlistURL, options: .atomic)
        print("Successfully write")
    }catch (let err){
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
}catch (let err){
            print(err.localizedDescription)
}
```

or using the Next Step equivalent.

But this writes the data as it is represented in the dictionary. I'm aware that the data itself is not in order within the dictionary so writing it in one go is probably not possible.
So I guess the best way to achieve this is to extend the dictionary one by one. Or are there any other ways?

Of course I can write my own Tokenizer/Lexer/Parser to read the file after writing and ordering it then, but before I start that I want to make sure, this problem hasn't been solved.

Comment: Yes, by definition, a Dictionary is not ordered - arrays are. What you really haven't defined well enough is what you mean by *"... in order of the keys..."*. Alphabetically? Time placed in the dictionary? And since you obviously want some kind of order, why *not* use an array? EDIT: Or at least keep this "order" you want in an array?

Comment: A plist is a dictionary, so even if you write it in some order, its still not going to be read in order and any mutations are likely to mess up the order.  this is why changing your info.plist always screws up the whole file when you look at the git diff.

Comment: @dfd in this case alphabetically order. But keeping it as in the array would be prorbably prefered

Comment: @Josh git diff is the reason I want to order them. to make merges easier

Comment: Pretty much the only way I've ever seen to "order" a Dictionary is with an associated array. Arrays are mutable, have counts and indexes, and can be kept in sync with a dictionary's keys. If your ultimate reason for this is something like git? Hmmm... seems like overkill to me, but on a project with many people having *access* to altering info.plist, it might be needed (or else locking down things a bit better).

Comment: xcode project files tend to get pretty large ;)currently i consider parsing the file by hand hand sort them without plist specific context.